# How can I "keep" the uploaded image on a form validation error?

Tags: django, upload

I have a form which has a `FileField` among other fields. Imagine the user chooses a file, presses submit and another field triggers a ValidationError. 
When I get back the form, with the errors on the page, what the user chose for the file field is gone. Can I make it appear, or is this a browser thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a browser thing - for security reasons, you can't prepopulate a file input, otherwise it would be easy to trick users into uploading files from their system without their explicit action.

Comment: So, every time, if you make a mistake ( which the client side validation won't catch ), you'll have to upload again?

Comment: If there is a field that requires server side validation (checking if a username is taken for example), why not use ajax to validate?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, so what is smallest change we can do to prevent having to upload the files again? I have never done it, but since we can keep the uploaded file in the server (by moving it from  the temporary directory to some other place) is there some way we can associate the file uploaded during last trial with the next trial when the user correctly fills the form without any validation error? If we could somehow do that, we would consider file already uploaded and process it accordingly.